# Can i add extra column(Such as primary key) to the existing table(satisfying rules), to convert to 1NF

Tags: sql, database, database-design

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bs7lb.png)In the above table there is no primary key , is it possible to add primary key column to any table if i have to according to rules, and will i need a another key column for Movies rented?
Please find table in comment , i am unable to upload the image

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bs7lb.png

Answer (score 0):

You will need another table, not just another column, for MoviesRented.  In this new table, there will be one movie for each row. 
Then you need Primary key for each table, and then a foreign key tin the Movies table that references the main table.
Failure to do this will prevent keyed access to movies.

Comment: If i create a new table making Address as primary key , and Movie Name as another primary key in other table . Can i create 3rd table making a composite primary key (satisfying 2nf )?